# Why lambda consumer for kinesis and KCL does not provide AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER for initialPositionInStream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am using lambda as kinesis consumer, TRIM_HORIZON and LATEST are cool for starting position but as the trigger cannot be deleted so what if i had to edit the lambda trigger configuration in future. I have no other way but to delete the existing trigger and create new one. And if i create a new trigger, all the meta info for the last failed batch is lost and after i create a new trigger, i am left with only two option LATEST and TRIM_HORIZON, which will obviously wont pull record from last failed batch.

My question is why lambda does not allow starting from a 'AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER' and also why cannot we edit the already created trigger, what stopping AWS to implement these two features ? also How can i make sure that after i create new trigger, lambda will start polling from the last failed batch position only.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this isn't possible. My advice would be to raise a support case if you have support and let them know you'd like this feature. Otherwise, there is an option in the console to submit feedback.

AWS uses this feedback when deciding what to work on next. The best thing to do is to provide as much information as possible.